# Slow initialization of multiple system.threading.timer

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

I have a program which check goods status of a website.

As I hadnt learn threading before, I simply use system.threading.timer in my program.

I have a List of system.threading.timer and a few system.threading.timer

```
List<system.threading.timer> _timerList;
System.threading.timer _timerA;
System.threading.timer _timerB;
System.threading.timer _timerC;
```

I called _timerA to check goods status and called _timerList to buy the goods with a account list of 10 accounts when the goods is up.

I execute _timerA per 500 ms.

```
_timerA = new System.Threading.Timer(new TimerCallback(submit_checkgoods), 0, 0, 500);
```

Inside submit_checkgoods ( _timerList.Add(...) is called earlier ):

```
if ( goodsIsUp == true)
{
    for (int k = 0; k < infolistbb.Count; k++)
    {
        int copy = k;
        _timerList[copy] = new System.Threading.Timer(new TimerCallback(submit_buygoods), copy, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

The problem is that I find that calling _timerlist[copy] to execute is very slow.

I used stopwatch to check the time of calling _timerlist to execute to the end of submit_buygoods and the time of executing submit_buygoods.

The exection of submit_buygoods is really quick but the calling process is like one by one.

After _timerList[0] finished executing submit_buygoods, _timerList[1] then go.

Is this a flaw of System.threading.timer when there is too many threads( actually just about 15 )?

What are the reasons? Any remedy? Will switching to Thread t = new Thread() helps?

Comment: Timer callbacks are executed on threadpool threads.  The threadpool manager tries to limit the number of executing TP threads to the number of cores available in the machine.  A wise strategy.

Comment: I searched about Task.Factory.StartNew. It is also scheduled on the ThreadPool and a StartNew does not guarantee a seperate thread. As i dont understand well about threading. Can you give me an advice what kind of threading should I use if I want them to execute separately and immediately?

Comment: It looks to me like you're using timers incorrectly. You use a timer if you want something to happen periodically. You don't "call" a timer. Change your question to describe what you want to do and let us suggest a solution. Don't just guess at what might work, because you're just confusing the issue.

Comment: Yes, I am using it incorrectly. As I stated, I dont know much about threading so I pick system.threading.timer. That's why I come to ask how did this slow initialization happen. I guess I am describing it well. The first comment did help a lot. "The threadpool manager tries to limit the number of executing TP threads to the number of cores available". The timer will first go into the pool and it does not guarantee immediate initialization.

Answer (score 3):

Use Task instead of Thread, they are better for short jobs.

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(submit_buygoods);
```

P.S. Maybe you shouldn't hammer the server every 500ms, you could get your IP banned.

Comment: I tried, same thing happen. But a thread = new thread() work. Anyway, thanks for helping!!